# $("#form").submit(); is not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I have two buttons(save, publish) defined in my form. If i Click 'save' and then 'publish' , publish button is not working.  The issue here is, save function works fine as expected. But when clicking 'publish', what happens is it tries to `submit` the form and rather to `validate` the form which defines under 'publish' function, it goes to 'save' function's validate function and further process.I would like to know why it skips that and jump to 'save' function's validate process?

The sample code;

**Form:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" id="manage_form">
    <div class="form-actions" id="saveButtons"> 
        <button class="btn btn-primary" id="save"/>save</button>
        <% if (outputs.isPermitted) { %> 
            <a class="btn btn-info" id="publish">Publish</a>  
        <% } %>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Jquery**

```
// cache var to eliminate unnecessary re-querying
```

var $manageForm = $('#manage_form');

```
$('#save').click(function (e) {
   var v = $("#manage_form").validate({
            submitHandler: function(form) {
            if(!validate_tiers()){
                return false;

            }
            var designer = APIDesigner();
            $('#swagger').val(JSON.stringify(designer.api_doc));
            $('#saveMessage').show();
            $('#saveButtons').hide();
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                success:function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
            //............
        });
    $("#manage_form").submit();
    });



    $('#publish').click(function(e){

    alert('xxx');
    e.preventDefault();
        var v = $("#manage_form").validate({

            submitHandler: function(form) {
             if(!validate_tiers()){
                return false;
            }
            var designer = APIDesigner();
            $('#swagger').val(JSON.stringify(designer.api_doc));
            $('#saveMessage').show();
            $('#saveButtons').hide();        
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                success:function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
                    $('#saveMessage').hide();
                    $('#saveButtons').show();                
                    if (!responseText.error) {  

                        $( "body" ).trigger( "api_saved" );       
                    } else {
                         if (responseText.message == "timeout") {
                             if (ssoEnabled) {
                                 var currentLoc = window.location.pathname;
                                 if (currentLoc.indexOf(".jag") >= 0) {
                                     location.href = "index.jag";
                                 } else {
                                     location.href = 'site/pages/index.jag';
                                 }
                             } else {
                                 jagg.showLogin();
                             }
                         } else {
                             jagg.message({content:responseText.message,type:"error"});
                         }
                    }
                }, dataType: 'json'
            });
            }
        });
        alert('zzz');
      $manageForm.submit();
    });
```

Comment: you are using `$("#manage_form").submit();` in `#publish` click handler that is why form is submitting on `#publish` click.

Comment: you validations are working fine just call `$("#manage_form").submit();` once validations returns true

Comment: UM, shouldn't the submit line be inside the submitHandler method of the validate plugin you are using.

Comment: @epascarello if i do like this my whole form is not working :(

Comment: I think the down votes are because you need to improve and clarify your question. The code you posted is incomplete or has some problems with unmatched braces. Is the id for the publish button 'publish' or 'publish_api'? Why are you using an anchor tag for the publish button? Why aren't you using <input type="submit"> for the submit button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prevent `default submitting` of `form` simply use:

```
e.preventDefault();
```

Use different submit handler for each button, This is what you want:

```
$('#myform').validate({
    });
$('#submit').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myform").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = function (form) { 
                                                                            alert('submit with submit'); 
                                                                             //your code
                                                                            return false; 
                                                                        };
    $('#myform').submit();
    return false;
});
$('#publish').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#myform").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = function (form) { 
                                                                            alert('submit with publish'); 
                                                                            //your code
                                                                            return false; 
                                                                        };
    $('#myform').submit();
    return false;
});
```

## [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7x5Lr46z/1/)

Comment: Can i see your HTML code @Ratha? Or making demo would be great.

Comment: Yes ..it is a form with all buttons. I provided the required button details..Do you need more? and the java script functions i used. I edited that functions with more detail And i dont know why people down vote the question here

Comment: It is continuation of this question. sorry i'm new to this Jquery. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424090/one-of-my-button-is-not-working-as-expected-need-to-refresh-the-page?noredirect=1#comment43293455_27424090

Comment: @Ratha do you want validation on form for both button?

Comment: Yes. User can save or publish or both. SO i need to validate in both cases

Comment: Sorry, i do not understand. I use different submitt handler in my original code?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66721/discussion-between-manwal-and-ratha).

Answer (score 1):

prevent the default form behavior of submit.

edit: wouldn't you want your submit in the submit handlers?

```
$(function() {
// cache var to eliminate unnecessary re-querying
var $manageForm = $('#manage_form');


  $('#save').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var v = $manageForm.validate({
          submitHandler: function (form) {
            $manageForm.submit();
          }
      });
   });

  $('#publish').click(function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var v = $manageForm.validate({
          submitHandler: function (form) {
              alert('yyy');
              $manageForm.submit();
          }
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried like your edited answer too. But still same behavior i see. Is this issue caused by my $(form).ajaxSubmit() ? I edited my code too  for your reference. It is continuation of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27424090/one-of-my-button-is-not-working-as-expected-need-to-refresh-the-page?noredirect=1#comment43293455_27424090